How to properly compute the product of two matrices in the dotted undotted notation?
Consider the term $\sigma^{\mu}_{\alpha\dot{\beta}}$ where $\sigma^{\mu}=(1,\sigma^{i})$ are the usual Pauli matrices in the dotted undotted notation. The latter has been introduced to me very roughly, so I am struggling in understanding some basic operations.
For example how do I compute the element $(\sigma^{\mu}\sigma^{\nu})_{\alpha\dot{\beta}}$? I can not understand what to choose between
$$(\sigma^{\mu}\sigma^{\nu})_{\alpha\dot{\beta}}=\sigma^{\mu}_{\alpha\dot{\rho}}\sigma^{\nu}_{\dot{\rho}\dot{\beta}}$$
and
$$(\sigma^{\mu}\sigma^{\nu})_{\alpha\dot{\beta}}=\sigma^{\mu}_{\alpha\dot{\rho}}\sigma^{\nu}_{\rho\dot{\beta}}$$
Naively I would say the first one, but I can't give a satisfactory explanation. I mean if the first have to be used then why I could not use also the following one
$$(\sigma^{\mu}\sigma^{\nu})_{\alpha\dot{\beta}}=\sigma^{\mu}_{\alpha\rho}\sigma^{\nu}_{\rho\dot{\beta}}$$

I suggest a reading of chapter 34 of https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf to clear up the idea behind dotted and undotted indeces. Pay particular attention to group theoretic relations.

In Van der Waerden notation, the positions of the indices of the generalized Pauli matrices $\sigma^\mu= (\mathbb{I}, \vec{\sigma})$ are given by $(\sigma^\mu)_{\alpha \dot\alpha}$. As a consequence, it is impossible to contract any of the spinor indices in the expression $(\sigma^\mu)_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^\nu)_{\beta \dot{\beta}}$. Expressions like $\sigma^\mu_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} \sigma^\nu_{\beta \dot{\alpha}}$ or $\sigma^\mu_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} \sigma^\nu_{\alpha \dot{\beta}}$ simply do not make sense as according to the summation convention one of the summation indices should be downstairs whereas the other one should be upstairs.
However, defining $(\bar{\sigma}^\mu)^{\dot{\alpha} \alpha}=\epsilon^{\dot{\alpha} \dot{\beta}} \epsilon^{\alpha \beta}(\sigma^\mu)_{\beta \dot{\beta}}=(\mathbb{I}, -\vec{\sigma})$, where $\epsilon$ denotes the totally antisymmetric tensor of spinor algebra, reasonable expressions like $(\sigma^\mu)_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} (\bar{\sigma}^\nu)^{\dot{\alpha} \beta}=:(\sigma^\mu \bar{\sigma}^\nu)_{\alpha}^{\, \, \, \beta}$ or $(\bar{\sigma}^\mu)^{\dot{\alpha} \alpha}(\sigma^\nu)_{\alpha \dot{\beta}}=:(\bar{\sigma}^\mu \sigma^\nu)^{\dot{\alpha}}_{\, \, \dot{\beta}}$ can be formed.

Ok, but then is there some relation for $\sigma^{\mu}{\alpha\dot{\beta}}\sigma^{\nu}{δ\dot{\rho}}$? Cause everything started when I tried to prove the relation $θ\sigma^{\mu}\bar{\theta}θ\sigma^{\nu}\bar{θ}=\frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{2}θθ\bar{\theta}\bar{θ}$. Should I use the usual relations of Pauli matrices right?

@Filippo Hint: 1. $\theta \sigma^\mu \bar{\theta} \theta \sigma^\nu \bar{\theta} =(\theta \sigma^\mu \bar{\theta} \theta \sigma^\nu \bar{\theta}+\theta \sigma^\nu \bar{\sigma} \theta \sigma^\mu \bar{\theta})/2$. 2. $\theta \sigma^\nu \bar{\theta}=\bar{\theta} \bar{\sigma}^\nu \theta$. 3. $\sigma^\mu \bar{\sigma}^\nu+\sigma^\nu \bar{\sigma}^\mu=2 g^{\mu \nu} \mathbb{I}$ with $g= {\rm diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$.
